# A function with changing variable, dependent on a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, onclick

So, first some background.
I have 9 types of rooms that are displayed as thumbnails with the name. What I want to do is that on click "Additional Information" - the rooms with disappear and the expanded version of a chosen room type will appear with the description and bigger picture. Also, there is an ability to go next and previous in the expanded view. I do not have a problem with this expansion and previous/next. BUT!

Here is what I am trying to achieve: if the code looks approximately like

```
<ul id="room_holder">
 <li><div class="room 1">Additional Info</div></li>
 <li><div class="room 2">Additional Info</div></li>
```

and so on...
And the expandable area will look something like:

```
<div id="expandable">
 <div id="picture">Blah-blah-blah, some description, etc</div>
</div>
```

So, basically, what I can't figure out is how to get the needed slide to show when the correspondint thumbnail is pressed. I know I can do the .addClass method, and copy the code 9 times, for each of the numbers (1-9). But I believe it is 9 times more compact if I have some sort of function, that gets the second class name (the number) by using .split(' ')[1] and then using it as part of the variable in the part which opens the corresponding expandable view. So, my question is: how do I do this? I am a newbie with javascript, but try to learn on the go!

Oh, and the codepen that I've been trying to deal with is:
http://codepen.io/godban/pen/QbZmxz

Comment: Why are you trying to use classes to uniquely identify the rooms? Why not use an `id="roomLink1"` or `data-room-number="1"` attribute?

Comment: Like I said, if it is defined through something-something-number it is a unique identifier for each, so the javascript will be re-written 9 times. If the function, however, uses a parameter of 'number', which is defined by the seconds class attribute - the code only appears once. I believe it would be a lot easier on the page, and considering that my page is already heavily equiped with scripts - I'm trying to minimise whatever I can. But otherwise you solution would suite me!

Comment: My solution *does* suite you, you just don't understand it yet. You'd write the code *once* and on click have it figure out what the `data-room-number` is for the particular item that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use data-* attribute instead of classes (new in HTML5) [data attributes, *w3school*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) :

```
<ul id="room_holder">
 <li><div class="room" data-room="1">Additional Info</div></li>
 <li><div class="room" data-room="2">Additional Info</div></li>
```

Then, use the click function from jQuery [.click( handler )](https://api.jquery.com/click/), use it this way to know which one has been clicked :

```
$(".room").click(function(event){
    var target = event.currentTarget;
    var room = $(target).data("room");
    alert(room);
});
```

Comment: I shall try, I'll get back with the result

Comment: okay, so I've tried it, but can't figure something out, namely why doesn't the line 
    $(".room" + room).addClass(room) 
work? If I remove the '+ room' bit - it works, but applies the class to all divs with class .room, not the one that has been clicked on. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was thinking, is the var room being treated as a string and nt a number variable? Could that be the problem?

Comment: Also, I have found out that the order of css matters too. So if I apply addClass .one and then .two - two stays forever, no matter how many times I press .one again. If I change the order of the css properties, so that .two is defined before .one, the latter will stay forever. What is going on?! Is there a way to return the function to the original properties of some sort? Or how to fix it?

Comment: You can use a selector that way `$('.room[data-room=1]')` it will select only room classes with the attribute *data-room* equal to 1

Comment: Yes, so I will have to write the code 9 times changing the number. But that brings us to the very start of the thread. =(
Is there a way, correct syntax and such that will select $('.SomeClass' + Variable)? That's basicly the only missing bit of the code that I can't get around

Comment: Yes of course, it will look like that `var nbRoom = 1;$('.room[data-room='+nbRoom+']')`, you need to know that `$` is just a name of a function and it require one parameter that is a string, so anything which gave a string is correct (string, variable, concatenation, etc...)

Comment: There's another way, but only if you use it inside the click function, you can reuse the target function that way `$(target)` it will do the same. and is more secure.

Comment: Ah! That's what I was looking for! Thank you! Yaaay! Unfortunatelly, I don't have enough reputation. but otherwise I'd mark you answer!